# javascript foreach select loop with selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've written the following code that generates a select list. However, the part where it's supposed to check if this.id equals the same as the existing_code and put the selected value in doesnt seem to work.

any ideas what is wrong?

```
function showHide(layer, existing_code) {

jQuery.ajax({ url: 'getdata.php', dataType: 'json', cache: 'false', success: function(data) {

    var codes = codes;
    var selectcode = '';

    selectcode += '<select name="codes">';  
        jQuery.each(codes, function() {
            selectcode += '<option value="' + this.id + '"';
                if (this.id == existing_code) {
                    selectcode += ' selected';
                }
            selectcode += '>' + this.code + '</option>';
        });
    selectcode += '</select>';  

    jQuery('.'+layer).html(selectcode);

}});

}
```

Comment: `var codes = codes;` - well, that's not very useful, is it ... you also have no '<select>' in `selectcode` ... so, you wont be creating a `<select>` element with this code - the returned `data` from the ajax is also ignored, so, not sure what you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
function showHide(layer, existing_code) {

    jQuery.ajax({ url: 'getdata.php', dataType: 'json', cache: 'false', success: function(data) {

        var codes = data;
        var selectcode = '';

        selectcode += '<select name="codes">';
        jQuery.each(codes, function(i, code) {
            selectcode += '<option value="' + code.id + '"';
            if (code.id === existing_code) {
                selectcode += ' selected';
            }
            selectcode += '>' + code.code + '</option>';
        });
        selectcode += '</select>';

        jQuery('.'+layer).html(selectcode);

    }});
```

}